# Why declare/initialize a same property both inside and outside of constructor?

Tags: javascript, class, constructor

From [Classes on mdn web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#field_declarations):

> Public field declarations

```js
class Rectangle {
  height = 0;
  width;
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
}
```

Aren't the `height` and `width` outside of the `constructor` meaningless since they're always overwritten in the `constructor`?

What's the significance of the `height` and `width` declaration/initialization outside of `constructor` in this case?
Are they used/reachable by any means?

Comment: From that same documentation: *"...By declaring fields up-front, class definitions become more self-documenting, and the fields are always present."*

Comment: "*Aren't the height and width outside of the constructor meaningless since they're always overwritten in the constructor?*" in *this case* yes\*. However, you could also declare public fields that aren't set in the constructor. [It might simplify the constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57609078). Therefore, in some cases, it's not meaningless.  \*[well, maybe some difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64358462) but I don't think that's what the example portrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The properties are only *declared* once (outside the constructor); if you didn't have those declarations, there'd be no declarations for those properties (they'd be created by assignment instead). Public property declarations (aka "public class fields") are optional, but can help avoid shape changes in objects (which improves efficiency) and/or reduce the analysis JavaScript engines need to do on the object being created to avoid shape changes. Basically, they provide a *declarative* (rather than imperative [step-by-step]) means of saying (in this case) that `Rectangle` objects always have a `height` and `width` property. While the JavaScript engine can figure that out using analysis of the constructor code, the declarations mean it doesn't have to worry about that (for those properties).

> Aren't the height and width outside of the constructor meaningless since they're always overwritten in the constructor?

The initializer (`= 0`) on the `height` property is pointless, yes, since it gets unambiguously overwritten by the code in the constructor and the assignment doing so is the first statement in the constructor. If it weren't the first statement, then code in the constructor would be able to observe the `0` in `height` prior to the assignment.

> Are *[the height and width declaration/initialization outside of constructor]* used/reachable by any means?

They could be used by subsequent class field initializers. For instance, this is valid:

```js
class Example {
    a = 2;
    b = this.a * 3;
}
console.log(new Example().b); // 6
```

It's probably also worth pointing out that there's a difference if the class is a subclass: When you use the declaration syntax, the property is created via "define" semantics (as though you used the `Object.defineProperty` function), whereas if you just assign to it you're using assignment semantics. That matters if the superclass also defined the property:

```js
class Super {
    #example = 42;

    get example() {
        console.log("Getting example");
        return this.#example;
    }
    set example(value) {
        console.log("Setting example");
        this.#example = value;
    }
}

class Sub extends Super {
    example = 67;
}

const super1 = new Super();
console.log(`What kind of property is super1.example?`);
console.log(propertyKind(super1, "example"));

const sub1 = new Sub();
console.log(`What kind of property is sub1.example?`);
console.log(propertyKind(sub1, "example"));

function propertyKind(obj, name) {
    let descr;
    do {
        descr = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, name);
        if (descr) {
            break;
        }
        obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
        if (!obj) {
            break;
        }
    } while (!descr);

    return descr
        ? "value" in descr
            ? "data"
            : "accessor" // presumably
        : "none";
}
```

Notice that `example` is an accessor property on `super1` (via inheritance from its prototype), but it's a `data` property on `sub1` because it was *redeclared* by `Sub`. If `Sub` had just assigned to it, it would have just used the property `Super` created:

```js
class Super {
    #example = 42;

    get example() {
        console.log("Getting example");
        return this.#example;
    }
    set example(value) {
        console.log("Setting example");
        this.#example = value;
    }
}

class Sub extends Super {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.example = 67;
    }
}

const super1 = new Super();
console.log(`What kind of property is super1.example?`);
console.log(propertyKind(super1, "example"));

const sub1 = new Sub();
console.log(`What kind of property is sub1.example?`);
console.log(propertyKind(sub1, "example"));

function propertyKind(obj, name) {
    let descr;
    do {
        descr = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, name);
        if (descr) {
            break;
        }
        obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
        if (!obj) {
            break;
        }
    } while (!descr);

    return descr
        ? "value" in descr
            ? "data"
            : "accessor" // presumably
        : "none";
}
```

Notice that now, it's an accessor property on both `sub1` and `super1` (and that when `Sub` did its assignment, the setter code in `Super.example` ran).

---

TL;DR - I would keep the declarations for clarity and potential efficiency, but remove the `= 0` initializer on `height`, since that value is clearly never meant to be used.

Comment: There is extra bit of semantics - public class fields would *not* be available to subclasses. Declaring the fields means they only apply to this object. This might not always have relevance but it might be worth keeping in mind.

Comment: @VLAZ - I'm not sure quite what you mean by *"public class fields would **not** be available to subclasses"*...?

Comment: Ugh, I messed it it up. If a public class field is declared in a child *without* initialising it, the parent initialisation is not taken for the field: https://jsbin.com/sopukacolu/1/edit?js,console I meant [this behaviour](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields/tree/main#fields-without-initializers-are-set-to-undefined)

Comment: @VLAZ - That's true about the subclass not seeing the super's value if redefining. To be clear, though, it's not that the initialization doesn't happen, it's that the field is completely recreated by the subclass after being created by the superclass. Public class fields are created using "define" semantics (e.g., as though you used `Object.defineProperty`), not assignment semantics. So in your example, `A` creates `foo` as a writable data property with the initial value `42` -- and then `B` redefines the property entirely as a writable data property with the initial value `undefined`. :-)