# How is 'this' bound in this JavaScript class?

Tags: javascript

I'm confused. How I was able to save a new method to the Test class using `this.outer`? I didn't think `this` in `this.wrap(3)` would have a value at that time.

https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-hopper-on7zhs?file=/src/index.js

```js
class Test {
  x = 1;

  addX(i) {
    return i + this.x;
  }

  wrap(i) {
    return () => this.addX(i);
  }

  howDoesThisWork = this.wrap(3);
}

const t = new Test();
console.log(t.howDoesThisWork()); // prints 4
```

Comment: Instance variable declarations are treated as if they occur in the constructor function. Thus `this.wrap(3)` effectively happens in the constructor, creating `this.howDoesThisWork` and initializing it.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57608525/what-are-class-fields-in-javascript

Comment: Also https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields

Comment: `x` and `howDoesThisWork` are [*public class field definitions*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields). They're processed in source code order at the beginning of the constructor (just after the call to `super`, if it's a subclass), and since they're processed in the constructor, `this` refers to the instance being constructed. (You don't have an explicit constructor, so one is created for you.)

Comment: Thanks all! `Thus this.wrap(3) effectively happens in the constructor`